# Laravel eloquent selectRaw for SQL injection

Tags: php, select, laravel-5, sql-injection

I have query:

```
$typeCancel = 'cancel'; $typeRefund = 'refund';
$query = Order::select(DB:raw('order.*,'
    "IF (order.type IN (?, ?), (order.amount * -1), order.amount) AS custom_amount"))
->where('provider', 1)
->setBindings([$typeCancel, $typeRefund], 'select')
->get();
```

And it work.
How can I do something:

```
... IF (order.type IN (?) ...
... ->setBindings([$types], 'select')
```

I try this:

```
$types = "'{$typeCancel}','{$typeRefund}'";
... IF (order.type IN (?) ...
... ->setBindings([$types], 'select')
```

But it not correct, result query see like that:

```
... IF (order.type IN ("'cancel','refund'") ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `$types = array($typeCancel, $typeRefund);`
then you can pass `$types` to your bindings